# Pointer Array usage

Tags: c++

I have a Movie class which has constructor takes 7 parameter like this;

```
Movie:: Movie(string ttle,string sts ,double prc,int yr,string gnr,Date rls,int id)
```

I would like to use dynamic memory for an movie array  but it gives error and i could not find it

```
int main() {


    int counter=0; // size of array
    Movie *moviearray;
    moviearray= new Movie[counter];    

ifstream filein("DVD_list.txt");


    for (string line; getline(filein, line); )
    {

        counter++;

        vector<string> v;


      split(line, '\t', v); // v is an vector and puts string words that has splitted based on tab

moviearray[counter] =(v[0],v[1] ,stod(v[2]),stoi(v[3]),v[4],Date(v[5]),stoi(v[6]));  // ERROR
```

How can I create an movie object in that array?

Comment: You are trying to make an array of size 0 because `counter=0`

Comment: i want to array size and line in the txt file is equal

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
int counter=0; // size of array
moviearray= new Movie[counter];
```

Does not make sense.  You are allocating an array of zero objects.  Later you use it.  This is illegal.

Instead, try:

```
std::vector<Movie> movies;
```

Then in your loop:

```
movies.push_back(Movie(v[0],v[1] ,stod(v[2]),stoi(v[3]),v[4],v[5],stoi(v[6])));
```